# How to refresh AG-Grid if i update or delete any cell value?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using ag grid with angular and i am facing issues as i have some mandatory editable columns in my grid and when i delete them, i want to change the bgColor of the cell to red. I read the docs and it shows that if i double click to edit, it automatically re-renders but its not happening. [https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/data-update/](https://stackoverflow.com)
The cell gets red only when i scroll horizontally but not at the moment i delete the cell value.

this is also what i have tried:
this.gridOptions.api.refreshCells({force: true, columns: [field]});

Comment: It's not helpful to troubleshoot your question when you withhold all information that would allow someone to understand or reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

please use refreshCells() or redrawRows().

https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid//grid-api/#reference-refresh-refreshCells
https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid//grid-api/#reference-refresh-redrawRows